# QuickSort: Can't understand the part when the Pivot swaps its position

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, pivot, quicksort

I found so many variant methods while learning Quicksort online.

Every time it confusing me at the stage of "Replacing/Swapping Pivot position" after the **Left/Right pointers** get crossed.

**Question: Replace pivot with Left / Right pointer position after each round. that's the question.**

sorry i can't find proper examples as i can't make it to suite my question. but please if some one have better example as well as **PHP code** of it?

Example: [81,70,97,38,63,21,85,68,76,9,57,36,55,79,74,85,16,61,77,49,24]
take pivot: 57

can take this example if want:
https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~cmoreno/ece250/quick-sort-complete-example.pdf

Comment: Swapping left / right pointer with pivot is Lomuto partition scheme. [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) doesn't do this and is usually faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to help you to make a question more comprehensible

Consider such scenario for array with N elements:

stage 1: Choose a pivot. (for example, random index or median-of-three)

stage 2: Put pivot in some position. For example, exchange value at pivot index with the last element. Pivot now is in `A[N-1]`

stage 3: Separate all elements excluding pivot (last position) - smaller elements are in `A[0]..A[l]`, larger elements are in `A[r]..A[N-2]`

stage 4: Exchange pivot (`A[N-1]`) with `A[r]`

What stage is not clear?

> Q#1: is it mandatory stage 2 to put the pivot by swapping it at first/last position? because i didn't found it in every example. some where it remains there and after 1st round it swaps it position with up/down pointer.

If you use the first or the last element as pivot, you don't need to swap it, otherwise swapping is mandatory. Note that pivot=first is the simplest method to choose pivot, but probability of the worst case is too high - for (almost) sorted arrays]

> Q#2: let's discuss about the memory too

QuickSort doesn't require additional memory for new array, it works in-place. Recursive implementation takes some memory in the stack (implicitly).

> replacing the pivot with the A[r] means the right(down) pointer position after 1st round, right?

Yes, it is down pointer position during crossing. Note - swapping with down pointer when pivot is in the end, but swapping with up pointer, when pivot is in the start.

> stage 3 How did it Separated?

Using partition scheme [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Consider Hoare's partition - it is simpler to understand.

Comment: ahh.. good start. thanks at least to start answering and trying to understand my question. i am just trying to learn clear the doubts and not here to gain up/down votes.

Q#1: is it mandatory stage 2 to put the pivot by swapping it at first/last position? because i didn't found it in every example. some where it remains there and after 1st round it swaps it position with up/down pointer. 
Q#2: let's discuss about the memory too.. i am not trying to make new array or variable or use the new memory. is it possible such way? or at least can use one extra variable memory? something like that?

Comment: here you answer i think the question: replacing the pivot with the A[r] means the right(down) pointer position after 1st round, right? that was my question.

Comment: also i noticed, stage 3
How did it Separated? using 1 traverse and with 1 pointer or the way i observed like 2 traversing pointers from 1 from left and 1 from right, comparing it with pivot and swapping each other's position if applies. 
See that's why i am confused as it might not be single method i suppose.

Comment: Ok, now i understood there are 2 partition schemes:#1: **Lomuto partition scheme** #2: **Hoare partition scheme**
in the next Answer by me, you can see the PHP code using _scheme#1_ with single traverse of array and 1 pointer. i think, this was the matter where i got so confused. Thanks @MBo.. it was simple but due to different partition methods, newbie like me gone confused.

Comment: Are your `$left` and `$right` new physical arrays or just aliases for the main array?

Comment: That's where my little concern is (this function i found on internet). in this it makes new physical array `$left` and `$right` . also there is no concept of `$leftPointer` and `$rightPointer` neither swapping operation done anywhere. (I don't have any confusion on those operation though)
What i got is, you already answered my question of swapping the pivot with which element exactly. (which was my actual concern)

Answer (score 0):

PHP code for Quicksort : (using **Lomuto partition scheme** i think)

```
<?php


$unsorted = array(43,21,2,1,9,24,2,99,23,8,7,114,92,5);

function quick_sort($array)
{
    // find array size
    $length = count($array);

    // base case test, if array of length 0 then just return array to caller
    if($length <= 1){
        return $array;
    }
    else{

        // select an item to act as our pivot point, since list is unsorted first position is easiest
        $pivot = $array[0];

        // declare our two arrays to act as partitions
        $left = $right = array();

        // loop and compare each item in the array to the pivot value, place item in appropriate partition
        for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++)
        {
            if($array[$i] < $pivot){
                $left[] = $array[$i];
            }
            else{
                $right[] = $array[$i];
            }
        }

        // use recursion to now sort the left and right lists
        return array_merge(quick_sort($left), array($pivot), quick_sort($right));
    }
}

$sorted = quick_sort($unsorted);
print_r($sorted);

?>

//RESULT: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 5 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 [6] => 9 [7] => 21 [8] => 23 [9] => 24 [10] => 43 [11] => 92 [12] => 99 [13] => 114 )
```